# How do I create a diagram of a ball bouncing using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to create a nice version of the diagram below using the tikz package. I am having trouble positioning the nodes in the correct places. How would I go about creating this?

[image: Bouncing Ball to Illustrate Special Relativity]

Comment: welcome-- would you like to share your code

Comment: This is un-physical. Whom are you going to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future questions please provide a MWE and read about [tikz](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf). You can use the piece of code below to get started.

```
\documentclass[border=3.5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=5pt]  
        
        \node[circle, draw=black] (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node[circle, draw=none] (B) at (3,0) {};
        \node[circle, draw=none] (C) at (0,-3) {};
        \draw [->,dashed] (A) -- node[above] {\tiny Movement of train} (B);
        \draw [->,dashed] (A) -- node[above, rotate=90] {\tiny Movement of ball} (C);
        \draw[red,thick] (A) -- (2,-2) node[below right] {\tiny Observed effective Movement of ball (D2)} -- (4,0);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am just getting started with tikz.